# How to describe loadbalances on aws cli elbv2 by name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elb

I'm using the AWS CLI to retrieve the load balancer IP to another EC where runs a service that needs the IP and Port(TCP) in a configuration file.

Recently we migrated from classic load balancer to network load balancer.

Using classic load balancer the name was possible to retrieve  it using the following command:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers \
                --load-balancer-name my-load-balancer \
                --query LoadBalancerDescriptions[].DNSName \
                --output text
```

But I didn't find any way to do the same using the elbv2.
How can I get the DNSName from it based on load balancer Name?

Comment: Are you saying that you tried `aws elbv2 --names my-load-balancer` and queried for `LoadBalancers[].DNSName` and it didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers \
                --names my-load-balancer \
                --query LoadBalancers[].DNSName \
                --output text
```

Use this.

Type below command in terminal to know all kind of options

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers help
```

Answer (score 3):

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --region <REGIONNAME> | jq .LoadBalancerDescriptions[]."LoadBalancerName" | tr -d '"'
```

This command can filter based on the Load Balancer Name. Also, "tr" command is used to filter out the double quotes from the beginning and end of the Load Balancer names. Replace `<REGIONNAME>` with the actual region.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.